# In React, why route can work properly without path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

code as below. `{...rest}` doesn't contain `path`, the route shouldn't route properly, but in fact it can route to path(/movies/:id). Why could that happen?

```
<ProtectedRoute path="/movies/:id" component={MovieForm} />
 
const ProtectedRoute = ({ path, component: Component, render, ...rest }) => {
  console.log("rest: ", { ...rest });
  return (
    <Route
      //   path={path}
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        console.log(props);
        if (!auth.getCutterntUser()) return <Redirect to="/login" />;
        return Component ? <Component {...props} /> : render(props);
      }}
    />
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the route still works is because you are specifying a `path` prop on the `PrivateRoute` component and this is the component the `Switch` uses for path matching.

A review of the v5 `Switch` [source code](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v5/packages/react-router/modules/Switch.js#L9-L46):

> ```
> /**
>  * The public API for rendering the first <Route> that matches.
>  */
> class Switch extends React.Component {
>   render() {
>     return (
>       <RouterContext.Consumer>
>         {context => {
>           invariant(context, "You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>");
>
>           const location = this.props.location || context.location;
>
>           let element, match;
>
>           // We use React.Children.forEach instead of React.Children.toArray().find()
>           // here because toArray adds keys to all child elements and we do not want
>           // to trigger an unmount/remount for two <Route>s that render the same
>           // component at different URLs.
>           React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, child => {
>             if (match == null && React.isValidElement(child)) {
>               element = child;
>
>               const path = child.props.path || child.props.from;
>
>               match = path
>                 ? matchPath(location.pathname, { ...child.props, path })
>                 : context.match;
>             }
>           });
>
>           return match
>             ? React.cloneElement(element, { location, computedMatch: match })
>             : null;
>         }}
>       </RouterContext.Consumer>
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

The `Switch` iterates over its children and checks for a `path` or `from` prop path value, and computes a match. For the computed match it clones and returns the matched `element`.

```
<ProtectedRoute
  path="/movies/:id" // <-- child component path specified here
  component={MovieForm}
/>
```

In fact, even something as simple as a `div` with a `path` prop will work, example:

```
<div path="/movies/:id">TEST</div>
```

This only explains the matching within the `Switch`, but now you're wondering why the `Route` component being rendered by `PrivateRoute` still works. This is because any `Route` not directly rendered by a `Switch` is now inclusively matched and rendered (*as if it were only in a `Router` component*). The `Route` has no path so it matches ***anything*** and is rendered.

It should be sort of obvious now that the `Route` component itself is rather irrelevant. You can simplify the `PrivateRoute` a bit; conditionally render a `Route` with all the route props passed through, or the `Redirect` to login page.

```
const ProtectedRoute = (props) => {
  return auth.getCutterntUser()
    ? <Route {...props} />
    : <Redirect to="/login" />;
};
```